# How to add multiple binary masks?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image: Conceptual Representation]I have a set of images(at different focal lengths) on which I have found the binary masks. Some these masks are overlapping and now I want to add all these masks together to generate one big mask of the images. Is there a way to add these masks together and consider the overlapping regions just once. While considering the overlapping regions it should only consider the ones with maximum edges(from edge detection).

So now mask has all the masks for all the images. Now I want to add these masks together. Any help is appreciated.

These are the original images and their masks.
[Link to images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wlitDYcZ9tyU3UrBR4N9B6M-Y6Cic_Ce)

So if orange has the more number of edge detected points in the overlapping regions it should be considered and green should have only the points which are uncommon. Orange and green are the two masks here.

```
for file in glob.glob("images/*.jpg")
      img = cv2.imread(file)  
      ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Comment: I do not understand the comment about "maximum edges". Please clarify and/or provide your mask image so we can understand better.

Comment: @fmw42 By maximum edges I mean the one with the maximum number of edge points obtained via edge detection. I'll add the reference photos of the masks.

Comment: Masks are binary. If you want just one mask, then when you combine them, you just add them together. Thus the overlap will not know which image to use, since the result is still binary. You would have to combine the resulting masked images using the mask with some priority ordering by labeling the mask image with the area of the mask or better just sorting the masks by area and then overlaying them in reverse priority order so that the largest is processed last.. I do not have code for that currently.

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for sharing that. But how to add the masks to get one mask?

Comment: Just add them and clip in OpenCV cv.add(mask1, mask2, ... maskN).clip(0,255). But that will not make the use of the one mask use the region from the largest mask, since all knowledge of the masks' size have been lost.

Comment: @fmw42 what do you mean by "that will not make the use of the one mask use the region from the largest mask"?

Comment: And since I have 6 masks how to I write them using the cv.add(mask1, mask2, ... maskN).clip(0,255). I can add them manually but there must be a different way of writing this using a loop I reckon because when I tried using a loop it gave an error missing 2nd argument

Comment: Sorry, cv2.add() only allows two at a time. But in Python you can add as many as you want. Just be sure to clip to the range 0 to 255. You may have to convert to float first and then back to int.

Comment: @fmw42 how to mention the parameters in cv2.add(). I have all the masks in "mask". How do I specify each mask as mask1, mask2,...,maskN.

Comment: See my comment above. I was wrong about the number of images allowed for cv2.add(). It only takes two images. So if you use that, you would have to do it in a loop. But you should be able to use Python to add multiple images together as result = image1 + image2 + image3 + image4 +image5 +image6. But you will need to convert to float, add them, then convert back to int and clip to the range 0 to 255. See for example, http://tutorial.simplecv.org/en/latest/examples/image-math.html

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to add multiple masks together using Python/OpenCV.

- Read the masks and convert to float in the range 0 to 1
- Add the masks using Python addition and multiply by 255
- Clip the resulting mask to the range 0 to 255 and convert back to int.

```
import cv2

# read masks
mask1 = cv2.imread('mask1.png').astype("float32")
mask2 = cv2.imread('mask2.png').astype("float32")
mask3 = cv2.imread('mask3.png').astype("float32")
mask4 = cv2.imread('mask4.png').astype("float32")

# add masks
result = 255*(mask1 + mask2 + mask3 + mask4)
result = result.clip(0, 255).astype("uint8")

# show results
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('mask1-4.png', result)
```

Masks:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Resulting Combined Mask:

[image]

**ADDITION:**

You can also do it this way:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read masks
mask1 = cv2.imread('mask1.png')
mask2 = cv2.imread('mask2.png')
mask3 = cv2.imread('mask3.png')
mask4 = cv2.imread('mask4.png')

# make list
masks = [mask1, mask2, mask3, mask4]

# add masks
h, w, c = mask1.shape
result = np.full((h,w,c), (0,0,0), dtype=np.uint8)
for mask in masks:
    result = cv2.add(result, mask)

# show results
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('mask1-4.png', result)
```

Comment: this looks amazing. I tried reading my masks in a loop and then applying the clipping but I got a black screen as a result. Any pointers what I am doing wrong. This is what I tried. ```for i in mask:
    result = 255*(mask[i])
    result = result.clip(0, 255).astype("uint8")
    ```

Comment: Is your mask a float image? If not then do not multiply by 255. In your case, it looks like result is being overwritten by each new mask. They are not being added. Perhaps you meant +=. Or try result = cv2.add(result, mask) for each mask.

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer for a looping way to do it without converting to float first.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple solution is just to use binary operations. If you want to join all the masks together then just use the | operator:

```
combined_mask = mask1 | mask2 | mask3
```

The solution is taken from: https://answers.opencv.org/question/123613/how-to-make-a-composite-mask/

Answer (score 0):

binary marks are just a matrices of size of the image having either 0 or 1 values, when a mask is applied all that happens is that each value is multiplied with its mask value, if the pixel is to be removed the mask value is 0 hence when multiplied you get a black pixel, if it isnt to be removed the original value is kept since its multiplied with 1.

To merge the masks, simply just addd the masks together, any area that is not supposed to be masked would remain 0.

After that simple do something like this

```
combined_masks[combined_masks > 1] = 1
```

This will once again convert your mask into a binary mask

So basically think of it like a venn diagram, if there were 2 overlapping circles as your mask, the union of these circles would be the combined mask

As can be seen below, A and B are your masks, and the grey area, their "union" is your combined mask

[image]

UPDATE ::: If you would only want the common region amongst these masks, you could still add the masks together and do the following

```
combined_masks /= total_num_masks
combined_masks[combined_masks < 1] = 0
```

UPDATE ::: Assuming you have n masks of shape img_w, img_h, this is how you would combine them.

```
unified_masks = np.zeros((img_w, img_h))

for mask in list_of_masks:
    unified_masks += mask

unified_masks[unified_masks > 1] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But when dealing with the overlapping regions I want to consider the region with the maximum points; meaning say consider this venn diagram's intersecting region where two regions A and B have some region in common. Say A has 10 points in the common region while B has only 5. Then for the final mask I want to consider whole A region and region B excluding the points in the common region(no duplication of points). Now think of these regions as edge detected images and A has 10 edge points while B has 5 I only A region and B excluding points in common region.

Comment: And it should be compared with all the images in the set. Say 6 as in my case. I have attached the images for your reference

Comment: could you maybe somehow illustrate this, its a bit difficult to understand

Comment: I  have added a picture to illustrate that.

Comment: i understand, so if you  have the orange circle with greater points we take the whole region, and only those parts of the green region that aren't overlapping, right?

Comment: exactly that is what I meant

Comment: so the union that im talking about, isnt it exactly that?

Comment: just give it a try, it achieves, exactly what you want

Comment: it is the union but I am facing is the number of overlapping regions in the images is too many and I can't figure how to add all the masks.

Comment: alright, ill give you a piece of code to do that, updating the answer right now